# 403 Forbidden in Big Sur using MAMP

Tags: mamp, http-status-code-403, macos-big-sur

After OS upgrade to BIG SUR I can't access my sites locally. I even set folder permissions at 777, staff, admin and user have permission to read and write, I've already checked the .htaccess file. I've tried everything and nothing works. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Same for me

- Check if you have the presence of an .htaccess in the parent folder (My case).